# Avoid writing swagger annotation in controller

Tags: laravel, api, swagger, lumen

I don't know my question is valid or not but the question is how I can avoid writing the swagger annotation in the controller. The only reason is my controller gets messy because of swagger annotation, its increases the controller line of code. If there is any possible way to separate the swagger annotation into a separate file that would great.

Note: I'm using the DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger package

Comment: do you use swaggerlevel or another package for the generation swagger file?

Comment: DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger, I'm using this

Answer (score 0):

I am too much late for replying an answer but might be helpful for the future purpose only.
Developer can use swagger-ui package which is not dependent on implementation of code and also not correlated to annotation.
I am sharing the link, you can go through and implement as per requirement.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Answer (score -1):

As docs says, you can put annotations to Controllers, Models or separate files:
https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/wiki/Installation-&-Configuration

Example from docs:
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/Examples/petstore-3.0